# Matplotlib bar chart with multiple columns and string X axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have two parallel series of data, for which I want to make a bar chart with multiple columns. I understand the idea is to shift each column by adding the width the x axis, but what if the axis consists in strings (categorical variables)?

Let's assume this is a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
+----------+------+------+
| Category | Val1 | Val2 |
+----------+------+------+
| A        |    1 |    3 |
| B        |    4 |    6 |
| C        |    6 |    7 |
| D        |    3 |    9 |
+----------+------+------+
```

Obviously, this will raise an error:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
width = 0.4
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=df['Category'], height=df['Val1'], width=width)
ax.bar(x=df['Category']+width, height=df['Val2'], width=width)
```

You can't add a numeral to a string.

So, what's the solution to get something like this:
[image: bar chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `pandas` plot function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.bar(x='Category', ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes! Just for the sake of learning, if anyone can suggest a solution in pure matplotlib, I'd be very interested.

Comment: For a pure matplotlib, shift the bars by `+/- width/2`.

Comment: I know that's the idea, but you can't with categorical variables. You can't calculate a shift based on a string.

Comment: Just plot against `np.arange(len(df))` and `set_xticks`.